# jQuery: Attaching event, calling event

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, bind

In one section of code I have this:

```
$("#searchbar").trigger("onOptionsApplied");
```

In another section of code, I have this:

```
$("#searchbar").bind("onOptionsApplied", function () {
    alert("fdafds");
});
```

The `bind()` is executed before the `trigger()`, but when I view the page, I never get an `alert()`.

Why not? What am I doing wrong with events?

Comment: Are you sure you have put that lines of codes inside the ready handler? Cause it works well for me. [Example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THZz7/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your `#searchbar` is not part of the DOM when you execute:

```
  // This will not work if #searchbar is not part of the DOM
  //   or if the DOM is not ready yet.
$("#searchbar").bind("onOptionsApplied", function () {
    alert("fdafds");
});
```

This type of stuff often happens if **[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** is outside the document ready or because `#searchbar` is added dynamically.

To make sure `onOptionsApplied` is bound correctly even under these conditions, use **[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** or **[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**:

```
// This can be outside document ready.
//   It binds all now and future #searchbars
$("#searchbar").live("onOptionsApplied", function () {
    alert("fdafds");
});

// Document ready
$(function() {
    // Whatever you do....

    // Make sure #searchbar is now part of the DOM

      // Trigger onOptionsApplied
    $("#searchbar").trigger("onOptionsApplied");
    });
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccEQu/)**

Answer (score 0):

I also tried it and works fine.

put the bind function in the ready handler and then trigger the event ...it should go smooth